# Clojure proxy multithreading issue

Tags: multithreading, clojure, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy for `ArrayBlockingQueue` that intercepts calls to it for monitoring

```
(ns clj-super-bug.core
  (:import [java.util.concurrent ArrayBlockingQueue Executors]))


(let [thread-count 10
      put-count 100
      executor (Executors/newFixedThreadPool thread-count)
      puts (atom 0)
      queue (proxy [ArrayBlockingQueue] [1000]
              (put [el]
                (proxy-super put el)
                (swap! puts inc)))]
  (.invokeAll executor (repeat put-count #(.put queue 0)))
  (assert (= (.size queue) put-count) "should have put in put-count items")
  (println @puts))
```

I would expect this code to always print `100`, but occaissonally it's something else like `51`. Am I using `proxy` or `proxy-super` wrong?

I debugged this to the point that it seems that the proxy method is not actually called on some occasions, just the base method (the items show up in the queue, as indicated by the assert). Also, I suppose it's multithreading related because if I have `thread-count = 1` it's always `100`.

Comment: @AlanThompson pretty sure `invokeAll` waits for the threads to complete. Also, the `(.size queue)` _is_ 100, so it looks like they've completed. Finally, I can manually check that `puts` isn't updated any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue with `proxy-super`: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2201

"If you have a proxy with method M, which invokes proxy-super, then while that proxy-super is running all calls to M on that proxy object will immediately invoke the super M not the proxied M." That's exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do the subclass via `proxy`.

If you subclass ArrayBlockingQueue, you are saying your code ***is*** an instance of ABQ.  So, you are making a specialized version of ABQ, and must take responsibility for all of the implementation details of the ABQ source code.

However, you don't need to ***be*** an instance of ABQ. All you really need is to ***use*** an instance of ABQ, which is easily done by composition.

So, we write a wrapper function which ***delegates*** to an ABQ:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import [java.util.concurrent ArrayBlockingQueue Executors TimeUnit]) )

(dotest
  (let [N 100
        puts-done (atom 0)
        abq (ArrayBlockingQueue. (+ 3 N))
        putter (fn []
                 (.put abq 0)
                 (swap! puts-done inc))]
    (dotimes [_ N]
      (future (putter)))
    (Thread/sleep 1000)
    (println (format "N: %d   puts-done: %d" N @puts-done))
    (assert (= N @puts-done)
            (format "should have put in puts-done items; N = %d   puts-done = %d" N @puts-done))
    ))
```

result:

```
N: 100   puts-done: 100
```

Using the executor:

```
(dotest
  (let [N 100
        puts-done (atom 0)
        thread-count  10
        executor (Executors/newFixedThreadPool thread-count)
        abq (ArrayBlockingQueue. (+ 3 N))
        putter (fn []
                 (.put abq 0)
                 (swap! puts-done inc))
        putters (repeat N #(putter)) ]
    (.invokeAll executor putters)
    (println (format "N: %d   puts-done: %d" N @puts-done))
    (assert (= N @puts-done)
            (format "should have put in puts-done items; N = %d   puts-done = %d" N @puts-done))))
```

result:

```
N: 100   puts-done: 100
```

---

### Update #1

Regarding the cause, I'm not sure.  I tried to fix the original version with `locking`, but no joy:

```
(def lock-obj (Object.))
(dotest
  (let [N 100
        puts-done (atom 0)
        thread-count  10
        executor (Executors/newFixedThreadPool thread-count)
        abq (proxy [ArrayBlockingQueue]
                   [(+ 3 N)]
              (put [el]
                (locking lock-obj
                  (proxy-super put el)
                  (swap! puts-done inc))))]
    (.invokeAll executor (repeat N #(.put abq 0)))
```

with results:

```
N: 100   puts-done: 46
N: 100   puts-done: 71
N: 100   puts-done: 85
N: 100   puts-done: 83
```

---

### Update #2

Tried some more tests using a java subclass of ABQ:

```
package demo;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
public class Que<E> extends ArrayBlockingQueue<E> {
    public static AtomicInteger numPuts = new AtomicInteger(0); 
    public static Que<Integer> queInt = new Que<>( 999 ); 
    public Que(int size) { super(size); } 
    public void put(E element)  {
        synchronized (numPuts) {
            try {
                super.put(element);
                numPuts.getAndIncrement();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println( "caught " + ex);
            } } } }
```

---

```
   ...
  (:import [java.util.concurrent Executors TimeUnit]
           [demo Que] ) )

(dotest
  (let [N 100
        puts-done (atom 0)
        thread-count  10
        executor (Executors/newFixedThreadPool thread-count) ]
    (.invokeAll executor (repeat N #(.put Que/queInt 0)))
    (println (format "N: %d   puts-done: %d" N (.get Que/numPuts)))))
```

results (repeated runs => accumulation):

```
N: 100   puts-done: 100
N: 100   puts-done: 200
N: 100   puts-done: 300
N: 100   puts-done: 400
N: 100   puts-done: 500
```

so it works great with a Java subclass. Get same results with/without the `synchronized` block.

So, it looks to be something in the Clojure `proxy` area.

Comment: Thanks, sure, that works. But the question is about my usage of `proxy`, not about how to do this per se.

Comment: It might be interesting to pose this question on the Clojure mailing list to get some more insight.

Comment: This is pretty weird to me too. I'm interested to see what the answer turns out to be.